# Default value won't set to Nil? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, option-type

How can I make the default value to nil?
I've tried to make the StockInfo optional in the `func stockInfoPerDay(jsonData: StockInfo?)` and `func stockInfoSingleDay(singleJSONData: StockInfoOneDay?)` but this leaves me with trouble in the for-loop.... It shows no errors when Force-unwrapping but I would like to not force-unwrap.

```
.onAppear(){
            stockInfoPerDay(jsonData: jsonData ?? nil) <---- *'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type 'StockInfo'*
            stockInfoSingleDay(singleJSONData: singleJSONData ?? nil) <---- *'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type 'StockInfoOneDay'*
        }


static var pricesForOneMonth: [CGFloat] = []

static var priceForOneDay: [StockInfoOneDay] = []

func stockInfoPerDay(jsonData: StockInfo) {
    
    CropPriceView.pricesForOneMonth.removeAll()
    
    for data in jsonData.data{
        CropPriceView.pricesForOneMonth.append(CGFloat(data.close))
    }   
}

func stockInfoSingleDay(singleJSONData: StockInfoOneDay){
    
    CropPriceView.priceForOneDay.removeAll()
    
    CropPriceView.priceForOneDay.append(singleJSONData)
}
```

Comment: If you want to make an argument optional then you also need to handle the case when it is nil, perhaps with a `guard` statement. So decide what should happen when it is nil and write code to handle that situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass nil to a function parameter unless that parameter is an Optional. You need to rewrite your function to accept an optional:

```
func stockInfoPerDay(jsonData: StockInfo?) {
    
    guard let jsonData = jsonData else { return } //Exit if you are passed a nil.
    CropPriceView.pricesForOneMonth.removeAll() //Move this above the guard if you want to empty the CropPriceView when you are passed a nil.
    
    for data in jsonData.data{
        CropPriceView.pricesForOneMonth.append(CGFloat(data.close))
    }   
}
```

Note that another way you could handle this is to leave your `stockInfoPerDay()` function alone, and use "optional binding" (`if let`) to only call your function if the parameter is not nil:

```
.onAppear(){
    if let validJsonData = jsonData {
        stockInfoPerDay(jsonData: validJsonData) 
    }
    if let validSingleJSONData = jsonData {
        stockInfoSingleDay(singleJSONData: validSingleJSONData) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ideally set it up so that your functions accept optionals as parameters and handle the nil case in the functions, often with a guard statement. However, since you said you had an problem with that and I don't know what that problem is, I can just suggest changing your code to something like this

```
stockInfoPerDay(jsonData: jsonData ?? StockInfo()) // <- Just make sure you have a good default initializer for the StockInfo object. Handle the possibility that jsonData was nil and StockInfo is empty inside the stockInfoPerDay function.
stockInfoSingleDay(singleJSONData: singleJSONData ?? StockInfoOneDay())
```

Let me know if I this helps.